# Spark jdbc write (to MySQL) missing milliseconds in DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

There are similar questions, but I am beginning to think mine is related to Spark jdbc APIs since both components seem to be working correctly on their own. I am using Spark 2.4 (which has ms support for timestamps) and have a MySQL 5.7.x version that supports fractional seconds.

I created a simple Dataset, with a TimestampType column, and when I show() it, here is what I get:

```
+-----------------------+
|my_timestamp           |
+-----------------------+
|2021-02-06 12:11:45.335|
+-----------------------+
```

When I write this to MySQL (using dataset.write()), it creates the table automatically, with SQL TIMESTAMP type for the column, and the milliseconds part is lost upon insert.

For a second test, I created the table manually and defined the colon as TIMESTAMP(3). When I manually insert timestamps with ms part to it, everything works correctly. But when I write using Spark jdbc APIs, once again the ms part is truncated and it becomes `2021-02-06 12:11:45.0.`

The only workaround that comes to mind is to keep the column as a long/BIGINT and convert it to DATETIME/TIMESTAMP when querying.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, StringType to the rescue. Apparently if I keep the Spark column as String with a value formatted the way MySQL expects, e.g. "2020-11-20 23:06:41.745", I can insert to a MySQL TIMESTAMP(3) column without any truncation or other problems.

This feels more like a workaround, so I still want to learn if there is a way to do this correctly.